# how to run or send sudo command in subprocess using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

how to use sudo command in subprocess to run sudo command in subprocess

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call(["sudo","ls"])
subprocess.run(["elpeto"])
```

how to call sudo command and enter password in subprocess so that it sends password in cmd

Comment: you can use sudo when running the python script and that is all.

Comment: need to run sudo command in subprocess and password should be also sent using subprocess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have You tried to use os to pass the password along with code?

**execute.py**

```py
    #!/usr/bin/python3
    import subprocess
    import os

    command = 'ls'
    runme = os.system('echo %s|sudo -S %s' % (input('Enter password: '), command))
```

Comment: PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: './debug'

Comment: try to make it executable in terminal: `chmod -x execute.py` and run once again